# toString() only printing default values

Tags: java, tostring

I am trying to use a toString() method in order to print out some private fields. However, whenever I attempt to send an object of the appropriate class to a print method, it only prints out the default values of each of the fields, no matter what I change them to. Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Here is the class with the toString() method (it also overrides another class which is where the getters are coming from). Sorry I am slow at editing this post. Not familiar with the text editor on here.

Person Class

```
public class Person
{
// Declare all the fields as strings
private String firstName = "", lastName = "", address = "", zipcode = "",
        phone = "";  // There are accessors and mutators for these as well
public String toString()
{
        String str = "First name: " + firstName + "...Last name: " + lastName + 
                "... Street address: " + address + "... Zipcode: " + zipcode + 
                "... Phone number: " + phone;

    return str;
}
```

Student Class

```
  public class Student extends Person
  {
    // declare fields that are not in Person
    private String major = "";
    private double gpa;

        // Declare accessor and mutator methods for the fields
        public String getMajor()
        {
            return major;
        }

    public void setMajor(String major)
    {
        this.major = major;
    }

    public double getGpa()
    {
        return gpa;
    }

    public void setGpa(double gpa)
    {
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }


    // Create a toString method that overrides the one in Person
    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "First name: " + getFirstName() + "...Last name: " + 
                getLastName() + "... Street address: " + getAddress() + 
                "... Zipcode: " + getZipcode() + "... Phone number: " +
                getPhone() + "... Grade point average: " + getGpa() +
                "...Major: " + getMajor();

        return str;
    }
}
```

Here is the entire main class... a lot of it is tedious code since it is a homework assignment, but the main idea is to:
"Write an application named CollegeList that declares an array of 4 “regular” CollegeEmployees, 3 Faculty, and 7 Students. Prompt the user to specify which type of person’s data will be entered (‘C’, ‘F’, or ‘S’), or allow the user to quit (‘Q’). While the user chooses to continue (that is, does not quit), accept data entry for the appropriate type of person. If the user attempts to enter data for more than 
4 college employees, 3 faculty, or 7 students, display an error message. When the user quits, display a report on the screen listing each group of Persons under the appropriate heading “College Employees,” “Faculty,” or “Students”. If the user has not entered data forone or more types of persons during a session, display an appropriate message under the appropriate heading.

MAIN CLASS

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for Scanner class

public class CollegeList
{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Declare the arrays of people
    Person[] people = new Person[14];

    // These three arrays are being made to print out the types of people
    // at the end neatly
    Faculty[] fArray = new Faculty[4];
    Student[] sArray = new Student[7];
    CollegeEmployee[] cArray = new CollegeEmployee[3];

    // Prompt for users input
    System.out.print("Please choose the type of person you are entering " +
            "data for.\nFor a student enter \"S\"; for a faculty member " +
            "enter \"F\"; for a college employee enter \"C\"; and to quit " 
            + "enter \"Q\": ");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String type = keyboard.next();  // the type of person
    System.out.println();

    // initialize counts of persons so that user does not enter more
    int facultyCount = 0;
    int studentCount = 0;
    int employeeCount = 0;

    // initialize index of the array to 0
    int index = 0;

    // continue until the user enters Q or until one of the types of people
    // overflows or until all 14 elements are taken up
    while (!type.equals("Q") && (facultyCount <= 3) && (studentCount <= 7)
            && (employeeCount <= 4) && (index < 14))
    {
        if(type.equals("S") && !type.equals("Q")) // Enter info for student
        {
            // Give the indexes the adresses
            people[index] = new Student();
            sArray[studentCount] = new Student();

            // Set the info
            personInfo(people[index]);
            studentInfo((Student)people[index]);
            System.out.println("\n");

            // Increment the counts
            studentCount++;
            index++;
        }

        else if(type.equals("C") && !type.equals("Q")) // Enter info for
        {                                              // college employee
            // Give the indexes the adresses
            people[index] = new CollegeEmployee();
            cArray[employeeCount] = new CollegeEmployee();

            // Set the info
            personInfo(people[index]);
            employeeInfo((CollegeEmployee)people[index]);
            System.out.println("\n");

            // Increment the counts
            employeeCount++;
            index++;
        }

        else if(type.equals("F") && !type.equals("Q")) // enter info for faculty
        {
            // Give the indexes the adresses
            people[index] = new Faculty();
            fArray[facultyCount] = new Faculty();

            // Set the info
            personInfo(people[index]);
            employeeInfo((CollegeEmployee)people[index]);
            facultyInfo((Faculty)people[index]);
            System.out.println("\n");

            // increment the counts
            facultyCount++;
            index++;
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter the next person type (S, C, F, " +
                "or Q): ");
        type = keyboard.next();
    }

    // Displays error message then closes program if there was overflow
    if ((facultyCount > 3) || (studentCount > 7) || (employeeCount > 4))
    {
        System.out.println("Too much data for one type of  person. Goodbye.");
        System.exit(0);
    }


    // Print the data for all of the college employees
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    System.out.println("THE COLLEGE EMPLOYEES");
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeCount; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(cArray[i]);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    // Determines if not all of the personS type was filled
    if (employeeCount != 4)
    {
        System.out.println("There are " + (4 - employeeCount) + " employees"
                + " who are not recorded.");
    }



    // Print the data for all of the faculty
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    System.out.println("THE FACULTY");
    for (int i = 0; i < facultyCount; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(fArray[i]);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    // Determines if not all of the person type was filled
    if (facultyCount != 3)
    {
        System.out.println("There are " + (3 - facultyCount) + " faculty "
                + "members who are not recorded.");
    }



    // Print the data for all of the students
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    System.out.println("THE STUDENTS");
    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(sArray[i]);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    // Determines if not all of the person type was filled
    if (studentCount != 7)
    {
        System.out.println("There are " + (7 - studentCount) + " students "
                + "who are not recorded.");
    }
}

// prompts the user for data input that is universal to all the people
public static void personInfo(Person p)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("First name: ");
    String fName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Last name: ");
    String lName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Street address: ");
    String address = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Zipcode: ");
    String zipcode = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Phone number: ");
    String phone = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    // Sets the data accordingly
    p.setFirstName(fName);
    p.setLastName(lName);
    p.setAddress(address);
    p.setZipcode(zipcode);
    p.setPhone(phone);
}

// Sets the data for student fields
public static void studentInfo(Student s)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Grade point average: ");
    double gpa = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Major: ");
    String major = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println();

    // Set the data accordingly
    s.setGpa(gpa);
    s.setMajor(major);
}

// Sets the data for Faculty fields
public static void facultyInfo(Faculty f)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Is the faculty tenured (\"yes\" or \"no)\"?");
    String tenured = keyboard.next();

    // set the data accordingly
    switch (tenured)
    {
        case "yes" :
            f.setTenured(true);
            break;
        case "no" :
            f.setTenured(false);
            break;
    }
}

// Sets the info for CollegeEmployee fields
public static void employeeInfo(CollegeEmployee c)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Social security number: ");
    String socialSecurity = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Salary: ");
    String salary = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Department name: ");
    String department = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println();

    // Set the data accordingly
    c.setSocialSecurity(socialSecurity);
    c.setSalary(salary);
    c.setDepartment(department);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please add code where you implement `toString`

Comment: can you include a full example please? Show us the `Person` class and the way you're creating a `Student` and printing it.

Comment: provide some examples with output values...

Comment: Can you show what is being printed to your screen?

Comment: @Dodd10x The output of each student object in the array is:

First name: ...Last name: ... Street address: ... Zipcode: ... Phone number: ... Grade point average: 0.0...Major:

Comment: @PeterKuebler - show us what you are seeing on your end, and what you expect to see.  I suspect you aren't setting your variables but think you are.

Comment: Bah when I find out what it is I am going to be really frustrated because it can't be something too difficult... typical comp sci

Comment: @PeterKuebler You're right, it was something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two instances of Student() for each entry.  You are only updating the one in the people array instead of the student array.

```
   people[index] = new Student();
   sArray[studentCount] = new Student();
```

Assuming you actually want to store the students in two arrays, change it to:

```
Student student = new Student();
people[index] = student;
sArray[studentCount] = student;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since i dont have your Person class implementation, i just ignored the Person class. Here's my code:

```
public class Student
{
    // declare fields that are not in Person
    private String major = "";
    private double gpa;

    // Declare accessor and mutator methods for the fields
    public String getMajor()
    {
        return major;
    }

    public void setMajor(String major)
    {
        this.major = major;
    }

    public double getGpa()
    {
        return gpa;
    }

    public void setGpa(double gpa)
    {
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }


    // Create a toString method that overrides the one in Person
    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "Grade point average: " + getGpa() +
                "...Major: " + getMajor();

        return str;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setGpa(8.88);
        s.setMajor("CS");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

Grade point average: 8.88...Major: CS

Probably you haven't set the fields of the object before printing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constructor with all your fields

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName = "";
    private String lastName = "";
    private String address = "";
    private String zipcode = "";
    private String phone = "";

    public Person(String firstName,
                  String lastName,
                  String address,
                  String zipcode,
                  String phone) {

        this. firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.zipcose = zipcode;
        this.phone = phone;

    }
}
```

`main`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Person person = new Person(
           "John", "Smith", "444 Some Lame St", "90210", "510-555-5555");

    System.out.println(person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that you should not be calling Person's getters to do `toString` in Student but should be doing something like:

`return super.toString() + "... Grade Point Average: " + this.gpa +` etc. `Student` shouldn't have to be aware of what information `Person` wants to show as a string. It should just return whatever `Person` wants to show as well as anything `Student` wants to show.

That being said, I agree with the other answers that state that you aren't actually setting anything in your `Student`. Could you please post your main method?

EDIT: Now that you have posted your main method, I can see your problem. The `Person` you are inserting into the `people` array is a different object than the one you are inserting into the `c/s/fArray`. Therefore when you print `c/s/fArray` you are actually printing uninitialized objects. If you want to keep a duplicate copy of the object, you should do something like:

```
people[index] = new Faculty();
fArray[facultyCount] = people[index];
```

Then both `people[index]` and `fArray[facultyCount]` are the same.

As well, you should not be using static methods to initialize the objects, but should do that in the constructors for those objects.

Comment: It isn't even printing out the Person's toString though.